# Trying to configure YouTube subscribe button callbacks

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

Below is the snippet of the code which I have tried:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onYtEvent(payload) {
        if (payload.eventType == 'subscribe') {
          // Add code to handle subscribe event.
            alert("hello world")
          });
        } else if (payload.eventType == 'unsubscribe') {
          // Add code to handle unsubscribe event.
          alert("asdf");
        }
        if (window.console) { // for debugging only
          window.console.log('YT event: ', payload);
        }
      }
    </script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UCGsSHWM4ZraLZ8k6m4q4g-A" data-layout="default" data-count="hidden" data-onytevent="onYtEvent"></div>
```

The problem that I am facing is that it is not firing any event on clicking the **subscribe** button. In the console, I can see the following error-

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __ytRIL is not defined

Comment: I also encounter this issue. Upon further investigation, I tried a scenario that after I logged in my account is to refresh the page then I successfully subscribed to the channel(which the user that reported this issue have done). There is no workaround but to refresh the page after logging in. Here is the open ticket regarding [Youtube Subscribe Button does not work as expected when user is initially not logged in](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8414), you can star it to be updated regarding that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Google bug tacking this issue: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8569

Please Star the bug so that it gets their attention.

It even happens on Google's own site: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button