# gettint youtube video's titles

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to get video's titles from a youtube page, using Chrome and CORS extension.

```
$.get('https://www.youtube.com/user/SERLYMAR/videos', function (html) {
var $html = $(html);
console.log($html.find('a.yt-ui-ellipsis-2').text());
```

It works, but after titles are listed, I got the following error (many times):

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __ytRIL is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onload (http://localhost/extract-titles/:1:2)onload @ (index):1
(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: __ytRIL is not defined(…)onload @ (index):1
```

Comment: See the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137734/trying-to-configure-youtube-subscribe-button-callbacks)

Comment: @FrankerZ, does it mean that there is no solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `dataType` to text to prevent your script from parsing the script tags in your remote page.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    url: 'https://www.youtube.com/user/SERLYMAR/videos',
    success: function (html) {
        var $html = $(html);
        console.log($html.find('a.yt-ui-ellipsis-2').text());
    }
});
```